# When std::sort become unstable?

Tags: c++

In example from 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort
I got same results with std::sort

Is it possible to prepare a few items in order, that would trigger unstability on std::sort?
It could be handy when writing unit tests, to check that sorting is really stable.

Or algorythm behind std::sort is stable on small vectors and it's impossible to see a difference between std::sort and std::stable_sort?

Comment: This is a tangent, but testing for STL behavior in your tests or relying on unspecified STL behavior in your tests is very brittle

Comment: You might try to compare result from sort/partial_sort for each permutation of array with similar element.

Answer (score 5):

The order of equal elements in the result of `std::sort` is unspecified. It's completely up to the implementation, which algorithm to use. It would be perfectly legal for `std::sort` to produce the exact same results as `std::stable_sort` on all inputs. That is, `std::sort` simply calling `std::stable_sort` would be a perfectly valid implementation.

So there are no inputs where `std::sort` is guaranteed to change the order of equal elements. It's not guaranteed to ever do that.

Comment: You're right that `std::sort` can do a stable sort, but if it actually calls `std::stable_sort`, the `O(n log(n))` guarantee may not be satisfied.